# prevent remount when component is wrapped in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that may or may not be rendered in a wrapper component:

```
class Video extends Component {
  state = { isFullscreen: false }

  render () {
    const { isFullscreen } = this.state

    return (
      <View>
        {isFullscreen ? (
          <Modal>
            <VideoView />
          </Modal>
        ) : (
          <VideoView />
        )}
        <Button title='inline' onPress={() => this.setState({ isFullscreen: false })} />
        <Button title='fullscreen' onPress={() => this.setState({ isFullscreen: true })} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Every time I press `inline` or `fullscreen`, the `<VideoView />` remounts. This makes it hard to add initialization logic to the `componentWillMount` method. I can do other checks in my application to make sure it works well, but it feels better to re-use the component that already exists.

Is there a way to recycle the `<VideoView />`?

Ps My project is in React Native, so I used some syntax / component from RN, but I assume the question goes for normal React projects as well

Comment: Are you saying that toggling between full and not full screen will restart the video?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124310/its-it-possible-to-get-react-to-move-an-element-rather-than-re-create-it-when-i,  you can try to implement this with css instead of changing DOM structure

Comment: @ChristopherNgo no, this happens to be handled well on a native level, but this would be a perfect example for it. (in reality, it is about timers that fade out the controls after several seconds)

Comment: @AvcS thanks for your suggestion, I think this is the way to go as long as its technically possible, but it isn't in my case, see also my comment on Bikram Jethi 's answer

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the  component with a wrapper and now toggle the styles for this wrapper based on state change. I guess that should work.

Also if you are imminent on reusing the modal component only, what you can do is define some CSS under a new className on the modal Component that alters the required styling to give an effect that the modal is toggled. Then add remove the className based on the state change.

Comment: This is what I would do if it were only style. A React Native Modal has some functionalities that can not be achieved by styles only. Maybe my question is more of a React Native - specific question after all (instead of plain React).